# Possible to check if a Listview (jQuery Mobile) contains a Collapsible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview, jquery-mobile-collapsible

I have a random number of `collapsibles` inside a `listview` element. 
What I would like to know is that if there is a way of "knowing" if the `listview` has any `collapsibles` in it before proceeding to the next page.

This [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M44FD/) pretty much represents what I have so far.

I would like some sort of client side validation that would check if the "user" has added "medicines" to the list (in a collapsible form) before proceeding.

I've tried playing around with this bit of code:

```
$("#medListLi").find('div[data-role=collapsible]')....;
```

But can't seem to know how to properly approach a solution.

Maybe I'm looking at solving this in the wrong way, any suggestions will be very much appreciated.

Comment: `("#medListLi").find('div[data-role=collapsible]').length` if returns zero, then there are no collapsibles. Else, it'll return number of collapsibles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector that you provided just needed `.length` attached to it like this:

```
$("#medListLi").find('div[data-role=collapsible]').length
```

When using a jQuery selector adding .length to the end always returns the number of matched elements.

So the above will return 0 if there are no collapsibles 1 if there is one etc...

To use this in an if statment all you need to do is:

```
if ($("#medListLi").find('div[data-role=collapsible]').length > 0) {
    // submit
} else {
    // error (no collapsibles)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a JavaScript condition that will evaluate to `true` if your `#medListLi` contains a collapsible element:

```
if ( $("#medListLi").find('div[data-role=collapsible]').length ) {
    //yup, their is something collapsible in here
}
```

This code does the following:

1. select the element with an id of `#medListLi` within that element,
2. find any `div` that has a `data-role` attribute set to "collapsible"
3. jQuery returns any such elements in an array; the `.length`
   JavaScript property will return a 0 or some positive number, which gets evaluated to false (for 0) or true (for any other positive number).